# How to set specific variable name?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, global-variables

If there is possibility to set a specific variable name in repeated function (object programming)?

I need to reuse this function and for every use I need the variable name to be specific (function property + a).

```
function test(test)
{
    var a + test = 'test text';
    console.log(atest);
}

test('test');
```

I need the variable `atest` to result in `'test text'`.

Comment: This is a frequently-asked question. The basic answer is that it is not possible to "construct" a variable name and use it as such (in JavaScript). It *is* possible to construct an object property name. Often people build strings that comprise the names of global variables and access them as properties of the `window` object, but that does not work for variables declared in functions. The `eval()` function is another (questionable) option. Finally, it's usually the case that there are better, more idiomatic ways of achieving the larger goal.

Comment: actually you could do something like `eval("var a" + "test" + "= 'test text';")` but it has some safety concerns and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: a variable in scope of a function is a different variable each time you run the function - specific to the function run, even with the same name... what else do you *need*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a scoped namespace like `myVariables` to be used as a dictionary, e.g.

```js
// this prevents keys like `hasOwnProperty` from being pre-defined on namespace
var myVariables = Object.create(null);

function test(name) {
  myVariables['a' + name] = 'test text';
}

test('test');
console.log(myVariables.atest);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is really a bad programming but the answer is :

```js
  window['a'+'test'] = 'test text';
  
  console.log(atest);
```